# What should be done with the JTAG TRST pin when target chip has only one RESET?

Tags: jtag

I get the difference between the JTAG `TRST` (Tap Reset) and `SRST` (System Reset) signals. If the target chip has these two pins, its wiring to a 20-pin JTAG connector is obvious:

[image]

Basically you just connect `TRST` to `TRST` and `SRST` to `SRST`. Each of the signals should have a pull-up resistor. That's it.

However, what if the target chip has no `TRST` pin? I found the following example, but I'm not 100% sure this schematic is correct:

[image]

This schematic looks okay to me, as long as the flash/debug probe (which you connect with a cable to the 20-pin JTAG connector) doesn't drive the `TRST` pin. It can read the value on that pin - no problem there. But if it would drive the pin low, then that would cause the `SRST` pin to be floating around 1.65V. That looks like a non-ideal situation to me.

> So, what should be done in this situation? How would you wire a 20-pin JTAG connector on a board where the target MCU has only one reset pin?

---

**EDIT**
Dave Tweed advises to leave the `TRST` open if the target chip has only a single reset line:

[image]

Comment: What does the datasheet for your chip say?

Answer (score 1):

TRST is an optional pin in the JTAG interface. The Test Access Port (TAP) can be controlled completely via the TMS and TDI pins, and for simpler chips, this is all you need. TRST simply provides a quicker way to put the TAP controller into a known state for more complex chips.

Comment: Thank you sir. But how should the board be wired in case the target chip has no TRST pin?

Comment: Connect TRST only to the chips that need it. If you have just the one chip, leave it open at the JTAG header.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I've added your suggestion at the end of my post (see the **EDIT**)